# Ubuntu laptop going to sleep on lid close instead of shutting down

Tags: 16.04, gnome, shutdown

I have my laptop set to shut down in the event of a lid close (due to tons of bugs with waking up on Ubuntu 16.04), but every time I close my lid it just ignores my settings in Tweak tool and just goes to sleep anyway.

I'm not sure if it's related, but when the laptop wakes back up when the lid is opened, it will automatically sleep again in ~10 seconds even if I'm actively typing the keyboard. This seems unavoidable - no matter how many times I wake it back up, it goes back to sleep until I restart it.

I'm using Gnome 3.

Comment: Is the HD an SSD?If so I dont think sleep or hibernate are reccommended.

Comment: It's an SSD (filler text here)

Comment: Try disabling sleep and hibernate.May be all it is.If that solves the problem,re-enable them  individually to see if only one is causing the problem.Hope this helps.

Comment: I already tried that, but unfortunately it seems to be ignoring the settings completely. I am not sure if it's a hardware issue, as this laptop was previously running Elementary OS (built on top of Ubuntu) and did not have these issues

Comment: Have you tried using default desktop instead of Gnome?Reason I mention this is because I recently had a glitch on one desktop,but not the other.it looked like a graphics card failure.Never did find out what it was.(did a clean install-end of problem)

Comment: The same issue persists unfortunately